# Is this second version of my “Fehl-her” homebrew race balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew-review, races

This is a follow up to [my previous homebrew question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188416/is-this-fehl-her-homebrew-race-balanced), in which the answers explained that, overall, my race was underpowered, prone to overspecialization and fairly contradictory in certain aspects (being essentially an underpowered version of the lizardfolk race in some ways, according to one of the answers).

While I still didn't have the chance to play-test it just yet due to not really having a party to play with at the moment (certain matters regarding time availability and other problems) and not knowing how to look for one on the internet just yet, I've made sure to take a better look at other questions of homebrew-review in this SE as well as some other homebrewed race examples in order to try to better understand the do's and don't's of a properly balanced race. I still made sure to try to stick with the [detect balance](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/1vq1kz6PRAbw5LHy6amH-bNb4OuB8DBXL1RsZROt03Sc/htmlview#gid=0) scale though.

As a result of the feedback on my last question, the main changes were:

- Changed the ability score increase to match the theme of a more agile yet durable race.
- Swapped 60 ft of Darkvision for 30 ft of Tremorsense as per the recommendations in my last question.
- Some tinkering on the raptorial appendages based on the feedback found in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148183/is-my-homebrew-awakened-bear-race-balanced).
- Ditched the bite attack, since it didn't really add any meaningful flavor and served more as a pointless trait than as a helpful one.
- Dropped the charisma penalty to conform to the 5e idea of not giving  penalties as a means of balancing a race.
- Did some rewording in certain areas.

The last real change was my attempt at adding a completely homebrewed trait which reflected their nature as stealthy predators and which I tried to keep in line with 5e's design regarding resource management. However, I'm still uncertain about its effective balance score, since I didn't really find anything similar to it in the official races (and results in some worries that I might've unknowingly made a game breaking trait, which is also why I tried toning it down by making it rely on strength to be used to its fullest rather than dexterity, as well as to give an eventual player that still tries to invest in strength something to use).

With these changes made, is this second version of my Fehl-her race balanced enough when compared to other official races?

> **[Fehl-her Traits]:**
>
> **Ability score increase:** Your dexterity score increases by 2  and your constitution score increases by 1. (+12)
>
> **Age:** the Fehl-her reach maturity at 5 years old and live up to a maximum of 100 years.
>
> **Alignment:** the Fehl-her strongly defend the importance of order as the most important thing to ensure proper functioning of their group, being usually lawful.
>
> **Size:** a Fehl-her grows no larger than 7 feet tall, averaging at 6 feet, weighting between 160 and 180 pounds. Your size is medium. (0)
>
> **Speed:** you have a walking speed of 30 feet and a climbing speed equal to your walking speed. (+2)
>
> **Languages:** you can speak, read and write in Common, as well as speak in Fehl-her. (0)
>
> **Tremorsense:** You can detect and pinpoint the origin of vibrations within a 30 foot radius, provided that you and the source of the vibrations are in contact with the same ground or substance. You can't use it to detect flying or incorporeal creatures. (+3*)
>
> **Built-in armor:** Your AC is 13+ dexterity. (+3)
>
> **Ambush predator:** You have proficiency in the stealth and perception skills. (+4)
>
> **Natural weapons:** each of your forelimbs has a bladed appendage, which you're proficient with and can use as finesse weapons so long as both of your hands are free. When using them to attack you deal 2d6 piercing or slashing damage. This is not an unarmed strike for the purposes of monk attacks. (+6)
>
> **Live feeding:**. Upon a successful attack with your bladed appendages while hidden, you can make a grapple attempt on your opponent as a bonus action. If you succeed, for every turn the enemy stays grappled with more than 0 hit points, at the end of their turn, they suffer damage equal to 1d4, while you receive 2hp. Once you have used this trait, you can't use it again until you finish a long rest. (+?)
>
> **Restless sentinel:** During a long rest, you can recover your energy by remaining motionless for a period of at least 6 hours. If you're not wearing armor, you can blend into a natural background, allowing you to hide without any cover or concealment, and if spotted you appear inert. You remain fully aware of your surroundings while in this state. (+3)

Balance score result: 33 + ?

(no synergy calculations were considered in this final point cost)

(*the cost of tremorsense was based on the scores for 30ft of blidsight with blindness beyond and for darkvision with 60 and 120 feet of range)

Comment: Does the sneak attack requirement mean only Rogues can utilize Live Feeding? If not, you may want to define what sneak attack means in this context.

Comment: @stevenjackson121 I meant the ability requires you to attack while still [hidden](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/5e_SRD:Unseen_Attackers_and_Targets) to be used. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I suspect I'm missing some context on what this race...is. Is this based on something from the game? From another source? It's hard to discuss the flavor element without knowing what flavor this is supposed to have.

Comment: The name of this homebrew race sounds like a cowboy saying "feller" (fellow).

Comment: @ProjectApex much clearer! I suspected thats what you meant, but since 5e players usually associate sneak attack with "any attack with advantage," the old wording left room for debate which the new wording does not.

Comment: The wording of the "Natural Weapons" section is confusing for me; why mention that the blades do a "total" of 2d6 instead of just saying that each blade does 1d6 damage?  Is there an implication that when you make an attack with one, you can attack with the other as a free action?  Is it a special action to make an attack with both?  I would either get rid of the "2d6 total" phrase, or make it very explicit how and why this is functionally different to dual wielding shortswords.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle I have chosen to remove it. Is the wording clearer now?

Comment: @Axoren to me more like Fehler, German for an error or something wrong.

Comment: @ProjectApex As it stands it's fairly clear; but the meaning now seems to be the opposite to the previous version.  If you attack with just your (e.g.) right-hand appendage, is that single attack intended do 2d6 damage (which is what I believe your description says)?  Or is it that this single weapon _would_ do 1d6, but you are always able to attack with both weapons at once as a single attack?  If it's the latter I would suggest making this explicit (see for example the Unarmed Fighting wording on p12 of [UA Class Features](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-ClassFeatures.pdf))

Comment: Wording aside, I do believe a 2d6 finesse weapon is substantially stronger than anything that that currently exists, and would create balance issues.  The Unarmed Combat style I referenced would also be a decent guideline for numeric balance (as the situation isn't that different): d6 for a normal attack, or d8 for a "2-handed" attack.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle I'm making changes already (not in this post, of course). I started to understand the place of natural weapons in 5e and why they're usually not a "viable" option at the late game a little better (there's no point in other weapons then). I'm giving some extra attention to the different classes this time to see how it fits in them with the changes, but I'll definitely keep the "sneaky cave dwelling bugs" flavor. I'm still confirming if the NW damage will be a d6 or d8, though, since I don't want the weapons they hold at high regard to get obsolete too fast in a given game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like the flavor of this race -- cave-dwelling ambush predators.

I don't view it as a problem that this race is specialized to DEX-based classes.  Lots of races are specialized to various classes.  The lightfoot halfling is pretty strongly specialized to rogues, and that doesn't bother anyone.

Here are two minor problems:

- as SeriousBri notes, this would be the only 2d6 finesse weapon in the game, which is perhaps too much of a boost to DEX-based fighters since their previous best available weapon was 1d8.  The Detect Balance sheet doesn't appear to allow 2d6 weapons at all!

(also, maybe rename "Raptorial Appendages" to something like "Sharp Talons"?)

- the "Live Feeding" trait, though interesting, uses very low damage and healing numbers, which will be nearly irrelevant at high levels.  Consider dropping the damage and healing, and just saying "Upon a successful attack with your bladed appendages while hidden, you can make a grapple attempt on your opponent as a bonus action.  Once you have used this trait, you can't use it again until you finish a long rest."  My guess is that's probably worth two points.

Here is a worse problem: this race has 35 points, but "balanced" would be 24-26 points.  You need to lose some stuff.  I'd probably drop "Restless Sentinel" and one of the stat points, and weaken the natural weapon damage die.  Up to you though.

Answer (score 1):

### Your problem here isn't 'balance'

Your problem is that you are making a race designed to mesh well with a specific class. You can get it perfectly balanced, but the synergy with the rogue abilities will unbalance it.

For example here you are allowing a rogue which normally uses a d6 finesse weapon to dual wield 2d6 finesse weapons, effectively going from dual wielding shortswords to dual wielding greatswords.

It really sounds to me like you want to make a lizardman rogue, but either don't like the lore, or don't think the abilities mesh well enough, so you are taking a bazooka to a fly and creating a new race, rather than just asking your DM to reflavour the existing lizardman, or asking for a few tweaks.

You identify the problem yourself that it is similar to other races, so rather than coming back with more changes you need to go back and ask yourself what problem you are trying to solve, and creating a new race doesn't sound to me like the solution.

Just take the Lizardfolk template, and pretend bite is called 'mantis like appendages that are super cool and fit my concept'.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the blades essentially do a two-handed attack, which does 2d6 damage (+STR/DEX). There's no dual-wielding abuse possible.

Comment: Maybe, I never read it that way but I can see how it might be. Think my main comments still stand though.